# Two functions same derivative at a point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I know that if $f$ and $g$ have the same derivative at every point in a set then, in that set, the functions are the same except for a constant
$$
f(x) = g(x) + \text{const}
$$

I have a slightly different problem. I have two functions $f$ and $g$ and I know that at some point $x$, belonging to both domains, the gradient vectors are proportional
$$
\nabla_xf(x) = c \nabla_x g(x)
$$
What can I say about the two functions at the point $x$? Is there a relationship I can obtain? Essentially I would like $g$ to be a function with "larger" values than $f$ but proportional gradient vector so that the unit gradient vector of both is the same.

Comment: Assuming $c$ is constant with respect to $x$, then $c \nabla_x g(x) = \nabla_x (cg)(x)$, so $f$ and $cg$ differ by a constant.

Comment: @TheoBendit The gradients are proportional at *some* point, not at all points.

Comment: Do you have any control over the factor of proportionality, e.g., it's constant on the level sets of $g$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang yes exactly!!

Comment: You mean yes, you know that property holds...?

Comment: Yes, it will be constant on contours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there exists a real-valued function $\phi$ of one variable such that $f(x) = \phi(g(x))$, then $\nabla f(x) = \phi'(g(x)) \nabla g(x)$ by the chain rule, so $\nabla f$ is proportional to $\nabla g$ with constant of proportionality constant on the levels of $g$.

Conversely, if the factor of proportionality is constant on the levels of $g$ (as indicated in the comments), i.e., if $\nabla f(x) = \lambda(g(x)) \nabla g(x)$, and $\phi$ is an antiderivative of $\lambda$, then up to an additive constant (which can be absorbed in the choice of $\phi$) we have $f(x) = \phi(g(x))$.

(Technically, we also need to assume we're working on a connected open set; otherwise we may have to pick different additive constants in each component of the domain. That's also true in one variable, i.e., the claim in the first paragraph is only guaranteed if $f' = g'$ in some *interval* of real numbers.)